# iOS chart showing before data has been retrieved from API - swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am trying to create my first live chart using iOS Charts and pulling in data from my database.

The data from my database consist of games won, drawn, lost.  These are Integers (However iOS Charts is requiring that they be Doubles but this is another problem).

My main issue is the chart is not updating with my data - it works if I manually enter data in the line i.e `let games = [4.0, 8.0, 2.0]`. But with pulling in data from the database I get nothing.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ShowCommunityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//********CHART VARIABLES**************//

var totalWins: Double = 0.0
var totalDraws: Double = 0.0
var totalLosses: Double = 0.0

//**************************************

override func viewDidLoad() {

    results =  ["Won", "Drawn", "Lost"]
    let games = [totalWins, totalDraws, totalLosses]
    setChart(dataPoints: results, values: games)

}

// ******* CHARTS FUNCTIONS ************

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]){

    barChartView.noDataText = "you need to provide some data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Games Played")

    let chartData = BarChartData()
    self.barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
    barChartView.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.granularity = 1.0
    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData

}

// ********* API CALL *****

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let playerId = defaults.string(forKey: "playerId")
    let email = defaults.string(forKey: "userEmail")

    self.personalSelf = true

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.xxx.uk/xxx/xxx.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "community_id=\(comIds[communityId!])&player_id=\(playerId!)&email=\(email!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                if let dict = json?["Stats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if  let total_Wins = dict["totalWins"] as? Double,
                        let total_Draws = dict["totalDraws"] as? Double,
                        let total_Losses = dict ["totalLosses"] as? Double{
                    self.totalWins = total_Wins
                    self.totalDraws = total_Draws
                    self.totalLosses = total_Losses
                    }


                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
        }
    task.resume()


}
```

My problem is that the chart is not updating.  I am guessing this is because the chart is being displayed before the data has been fetched?

....On a side note, I would prefer to show `Int` and not `Floats` but it is requiring everything be a `double`

Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE:

Solution working- is showing floats rather than Ints and missing label from bottom of graph, is showing numbers instead of "Won", "Drawn", "Lost"

[image]

Comment: self.totalLosses = total_Losses after this just call your setupchart method

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: brother check my answer you got hint .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.totalWins = total_Wins
 self.totalDraws = total_Draws
 self.totalLosses = total_Losses
```

// add this lines in your response

```
results =  ["Won", "Drawn", "Lost"]
let games = [total_Wins, total_Draws, total_Losses]
setChart(dataPoints: results, values: games)
```

Check output.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Do I have to show the results as floats? also, do you know how I show the labels? For some reason it is showing numbers across the bottom?  (I will update question)

Comment: @RDowns now you have to just convert your result into decimal to float

Comment: let games = [total_Wins, total_Draws, total_Losses] before this line you have to convert your value into integer or float whatever your requirement. @RDowns